# RazorEngine Could not resolve template

Tags: razorengine

I have a console application that uses RazorEngine to send email based on the run of the application. I am successfully able to send emails both in the development IDE and from running the console application via the executable. However when I run the console application from a scheduled task I receive an error "Could not resolve template" on line,

```
var emailHtmlBody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile("ResponseErrors.cshtml", null, model);
```

has anyone run into this?

```
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
 {
    TemplateManager = new ResolvePathTemplateManager(new[] {"EmailTemplates"}),
    DisableTempFileLocking = true
 };

 Engine.Razor = RazorEngineService.Create(config);
 var emailHtmlBody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile("ResponseErrors.cshtml", null, model);
```

UPDATE 1:

- The server that is executing the scheduled task is the same server where the console app resides.
- The account that is executing the console app in the Scheduled Task is a domain account with local admin rights to the server.

UPDATE 2:

There is no RazorEngine... folder that was created in the user's temp folder.

UPDATE 3:

I just created a sample console app and it's now doing the same thing in the IDE. I put it up on [GitHub as RazorEngine_Test](https://github.com/tbconrad/RazorEngine_Test.git)

UPDATE 4:

It seems that the TemplateServiceConfiguration is not working as designed or the examples I worked off of are incorrect. I updated the test project with the 2 lines below and that solved my issue. I don't think this was the intended implementation method but it works. Posting because I know someone will run into the same issue.

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string filePath = $"{path}EmailTemplates\\ExceptionEmail.cshtml";
```

Comment: I figured out the problem with this project. The Templates were not set to copy to deployment directory so they weren't available at runtime. This, however, is not the problem in the production environment. The templates are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to confirm the fix in Production today. Adding those 2 lines did correct the problem. So the complete code block for this is

```
 var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
 {
    TemplateManager = new ResolvePathTemplateManager(new[] {"EmailTemplates"}),
    DisableTempFileLocking = true
 };

 string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 string filePath = $"{path}EmailTemplates\\ExceptionEmail.cshtml";

 Engine.Razor = RazorEngineService.Create(config);
 var emailHtmlBody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(filePath, null, model);
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same Problem my solution was changing the Project file `ProjectName.csproj` external and adding the View as content and not as None
from

```
    <None Include="Views/Folder/Name.cshtml"/>
```

to

```
    <Content Include="Views\Emails\Name.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```